# How to get process id of multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()?

Tags: python, multithreading

Normally we can get the pid of multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()  in below way

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> manager =  multiprocessing.Manager()
>>> queue  =  manager.Queue()
>>> queue._manager._process.pid
32638
```

But sometimes the queue._manager  will return None in my code.

So my question is why queue._manager will return None?
How to get pid of the queue in this kind of situation?